# django-storages boto3 accessing file url of a private file

Tags: python, django, boto3

I'm trying to get the generated URL of a file in a test model I've created,
and I'm trying to get the correct url of the file by: `modelobject.file.url` which does give me the correct url if the file is public, however if the file is private it does not automatically generate a signed url for me, how is this normally done with django-storages?

Is the API supposed to automatically generate a signed url for private files? I am getting the expected Access Denied Page for 'none' signed urls currently, and need to get the signed 'volatile' link to the file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I've figured out what I needed to do,

in the Private Storage class, I forgot to put `custom_domain = False` originally left this line off, because I did not think I needed it however you absolutely do in order to generate signed urls automatically.

Comment: Just had this exact problem. Thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: I think I'm facing this same issue - where are you setting `custom_domain = False`?  I'm not sure what you meant by Private Storage class.

Comment: @Andrew See this excellent tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/

Comment: In my case the problem I had with the private storage engine was with the `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` setting param, which `cookiecutter-django` apparently sets to `False`.