# Django Admin S3 Private Media Files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

When using the private media django-storages class below. When I view the uploaded file in the admin it does not generate the URL Query String Authorization parameters.

```py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class PrivateMediaRootTenantedS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    auto_create_bucket = True
    default_acl = "private"
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django) sets the `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` value to `False` when [its default is `True`](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings).

Additional reference about the `custom_domain` variable needing to be `False` can be found in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913046/django-storages-boto3-accessing-file-url-of-a-private-file).